# Ubuntu freezes when battery gets empty

Tags: gnome, 16.04, suspend

I have observed this phenomenon several times with Ubuntu 2016.04 with Gnome:

1. I forget to plug the power cord into the wall
2. I launch gmusicbrowser and make it play music
3. I put my laptop on the shelf where nobody can touch it
4. I party with my friends without anyone touching the computer
5. After a few hours, suddenly the music starts looping, for instance if the artist was singing "♪never gonna♫" the sound "nenenenenenenene..." is played indefinitely
6. Keyboard and mouse do not work, CTRL-ALT-F1 does not work either
7. Only option is to press the ON/OFF button for a few seconds to hard reboot

**QUESTION**: How can I investigate this problem?
Any idea what could be causing it, or what is preventing Ubuntu from going to sleep/suspend mode cleanly?

Comment: See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1599264) and [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-doc/2016-July/020105.html).

Comment: @DougSmythies: Could you please explain why you think these seemingly unrelated links are actually relevant to my question? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Because they explain why your battery is going to such a low level that things don't work properly, instead of suspending at some battery level that is still safe.